# Python computing quiz

Tags: python, python-3.x, quiz

The following code is a computing quiz:

```
import random

#the questions/answer dictionary
my_dict =   {
            "Base-2 number system" : "binary",
            "Number system that uses the characters 0-F" : "hexidecimal",
            "7-bit text encoding standard" : "ascii",
            "16-bit text encoding standard" : "unicode",
            "A number that is bigger than the maximum number that can be          stored" : "overflow",
            "8 bits" : "byte",
            "1024 bytes" : "kilobyte",
            "Picture Element. The smallest component of a bitmapped image" : "pixel",
            "A continuously changing wave, such as natural sound" : "analogue",
            "the number of times per second that a wave is measured" : "sample rate",
            "A binary representation of a program" : "machine code"
        }

#welcome message
print("Computing Revision Quiz")
print("=======================")

#the quiz will end when this variable becomes 'False'
playing = True

#While the game is running
while playing == True:

    #set the score to 0
    score = 0

    #gets the number of questions the player wants to answer
    num = int(input("\nHow many questions would you like: "))

    #loop the correct number of times
    for i in range(num):

        #the question is one of the dictionary keys, picked at random
        question = (random.choice( list(my_dict.keys())))
        #the answer is the string mapped to the question key
        answer = my_dict[question]

        #print the question, along with the question number
        print("\nQuestion " + str(i+1) )
        print(question  + "?")

        #get the user's answer attempt
        guess = input("> ")

        #if their guess is the same as the answer
        if guess.lower() == answer.lower():
            #add 1 to the score and print a message
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("Nope!")

    #after the quiz, print their final score  
    print("\nYour final score was " + str(score))

    #store the user's input...
    again = input("Enter any key to play again, or 'q' to quit.")

    #... and quit if they types 'q'
    if again.lower() == 'q':
        playing = False
```

Comment: What specifically about your code are you looking to improve?

Comment: It is common practice not to post too many review questions at the same time. Although your other questions is currently on-hold, you should focus on one questions at the time... And it seems like you're having indentation issues here as well...

Comment: Please note that normally having this much errors in your indentations is a close reason (as you've experienced) in your other post. And code should not be edited after posting, so take on the next post (or when editing your closed post) that the indentation is correct and the same as in your editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just some general syntax notes I have after a quick scan of your code...

### Python isn't C, not all evaluations are about equality!

The line `while playing == True:`, **immediately** struck me as odd.  Python *evaluates* things in if-statements/while-loops/etc.  This is different to a language such as [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29), which always uses **equality** (or inequality) for such things.

Specifically, if we take the variable `playing` to just be `(something that is either True or False)`, and then substitute that into the expression.. We get:

```
(something that is either True or False) == True
```

This will *****ALWAYS***** evaluate to the same value as just using `playing` - since it's already either True or False.

---

### Input checking, <sup><sub>and why (when dealing with users) even sane people validate</sub></sup>

The following excerpt:

> ```
> #gets the number of questions the player wants to answer
> num = int(input("\nHow many questions would you like: "))
> ```

As you've discovered, `input` is returning you a string, and the way to *cast* this to an int is with (the appropriately named) `int`.  However, if a user enters something like "Tersosaur" instead of a *number*, you will get a `ValueError` (raised by `int`).

The way to deal with this is to use a [try/except](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions), like this:

```
#gets the number of questions the player wants to answer
num = input("\nHow many questions would you like: ")
try:
    num = int(num)
except ValueError:
    print "Error '%s' is not a valid number".format(num)
```

---

### <sub>Just a recommendation,</sub>  Make your code more Pythonic

I noticed a lot (all) of your initialization and start-up code (things such as setting `score = 0`, etc) **happens in the program itself**, and not in a [**main**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) block.

You don't technically *need* this, but it is best practise to use a block like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...initialization code goes here
```

---

### [Functional Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_%28computer_science%29) is your <strike>[frenemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenemy)</strike> friend

[Functional Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_%28computer_science%29) is ***important***, even in small program like this.  It improves the readability, understandability and (perhaps most importantly here) maintainability of your code.

At the moment, all of your logic is wrapped up inside this *mainloop* style sequence of commands.  The *way* you get input from the user, the *way* you keep score, *how* you check if their answers are correct, etc.  All of these **ways and hows** are *behaviours*, which in Python ***can***<sup>***</sup> become *methods*.

* Note: [Functional Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decomposition_%28computer_science%29) is not ALWAYS your friend (hence [frenemy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenemy)).  If you go to far you'll end up with just as big a mess of spaghetti code as you started with.  For example, don't extract each and every line from your loop into a separate function and think it's functionally decomposed.  Functional decomposition is about the *identification* of behaviours.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann Yes, you *could* do `while (playing) {` in C99, assuming `playing` as a `bool`, or in ANSI C (C89) if `playing` were an `int`.  However, Python doesn't have stack ints or bools, **everything is a pointer**.  And if `playing` is an `int*`, then you most certainly cannot just do `while (playing) {`(unless, of course, your plan is that users have to keep playing until you cause a stack overflow to get `playing` to stop being positive.
But I suppose you're right, it's not immediately clear to any inexperienced C programmers what is meant with that comparison.

Comment: @Tersosauros Why would you make `playing` an `int*`? It should clearly be a `bool` (or `int`) in C as well. I doubt it's about my C experience, I think it's just not at all an example for the argument your trying to force into this.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann C89 (ANSI standard C) doesn't have `bool`, as I pointed out.  And Python doesn't have stack types, as I also pointed out.  I don't think I'm the one trying to force anything?  As I said, the comparison may not be immediately clear.  Perhaps you should suggest an edit if you believe it can be so easily improved?

Comment: I know it doesn't have `bool`, that's why I said "or `int`". Why do you point it out again? And no idea what your point is with stack types (as you just stated it without making a point about it) and why you think I didn't read it. You are trying to force a C comparison into this. If I were to edit it, I'd just take out the talk about C and just point out that `== True` is pointless here.